# Delegate found Nil after setting the delegate correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my `StrechyHeaderLayout` class I am creating one protocol.

```
protocol StrechyHeaderLayoutDelegate : class {        
    func manipulateHeaderView(sender: StrechyHeaderLayout)        
}
```

And in this class I am declaring a delegate.

```
var delegate : StrechyHeaderLayoutDelegate?
```

And I am using this protocol in my `ScheduleViewController` class.
I am creating a variable `StrechyHeaderLayoutObj` as a class global variable

```
class ScheduleViewController: UICollectionViewController,StrechyHeaderLayoutDelegate {
   let StrechyHeaderLayoutObj = StrechyHeaderLayout()
   ...
}
```

I am assigning the delegate in `viewDidLoad()`

```
StrechyHeaderLayoutObj.delegate = self
```

The delegate is being set but when `StrechyHeaderLayout` is being called the delegate is found `nil`.

I am trying to access the delegate inside this method

```
   override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {    
           delegate!.manipulateHeaderView(self)
   }
```

But it is throwing error:
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Comment: layoutAttributesForElementsInRect is probably called before viewDidLoad

Comment: Your `delegate` should also probably be `weak` to prevent retain cycles – and you definitely shouldn't be force unwrapping it.

Comment: As another nit pick, try to avoid starting your variable names with a capital letter. Thats reserved for class names.

Comment: No, viewDidLoad is called before layoutAttributesForElementsInRect @EricD